# FileNotFoundError: Cannot find file when downloading zip file from GitHub on Google Colab

Tags: python, github, download, zip, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to work with [this](https://github.com/RomRoc/objdet_fizyr_colab/blob/master/goat_dataset.zip) dataset on `Google Colab`, but when I try to `download` it with this piece of code:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download("https://github.com/RomRoc/objdet_fizyr_colab/blob/master/goat_dataset.zip")
```

I get this message:

> FileNotFoundError: Cannot find file: https://github.com/RomRoc/objdet_fizyr_colab/blob/master/goat_dataset.zip

I downloaded this `zip` by hand and extracted it, everything is alright, but not in `Colab`, where I tried to download the `file` with `wget` and `urllib.request.urlretrieve`, but it just download `64.29K` of the file, that originally have `12.5 MB`.

Answer (score 0):

This is WAI. From the documentation

> `files.download` will invoke a browser download of the file to your local computer.